# Update trigger seemingly won't fire if multiple rows are updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have table_a and table_b, below is the data from table_a.

table_a

```
Bill_No   P_Name  Price   Stock_in  Stock_out  Stock_in_hand  P_Value
1         fish     100       20        10            10          1000
2         water    50        40        30            10          500
3         soda     30        50        10            40          1200 
4         cake     5         10        10             0          0
```

Now whenever Stock_out gets updated I want to insert those updated rows into table_b via a TRIGGER. Bill_No is identity column and primary key here.
This is what I have tried so far.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[copytblab] 
   ON  [dbo].[table_a]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF (UPDATE(Stock_out))
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT table_b(Bill_No,P_Name,Price,Stock_in,Stock_out,Stock_in_hand, P_Value)
    SELECT i.Bill_No,i.P_Name,i.Price,i.Stock_in,i.Stock_out,i.Stock_in_hand,i.P_Value FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
    ON i.Bill_No = d.Bill_No
    AND i.Stock_out <> d.Stock_out
END
```

The code works fine if I update a single row but If i update more than one row at one time then it does not send Stock_out, P_Value and Stock_in_hand values to table_b. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Have you verified that your multi-row updates alter the value in the `Stock_out` column? Your `insert` is inside a conditional.
Also, could you please provide a more specific post title? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the updates do work, multiple rows get updated at once.

Comment: Have you done a sanity check that the trigger is actually fired by the statement? SQL Server supports multi-row triggers so it definitely should. Outside of the conditional, log some stuff to a throwaway table (don't use temporary tables (the `#` notation), declare the table). Also run SQL Server Profiler at the same time to monitor what statements are going through the pipe (and include the Exception class).
Also, consider if there is any rollback occurring. I swear I recall seeing you tag C# initially, so also be suspicious of error swallowing by your application.

Comment: What @Elaskanator says. You could just comment out the `SET NOCOUNT ON` line and run an update in SSMS to see if the trigger generates its own "xxx row(s) affected" message as an indication whether it's actually doing its job.

Comment: @Elaskanator: Re: the C# tag, I removed it as irrelevant, although in this case it seems to have communicated a useful bit of information to you. Do you think it should be put back?

Comment: I thought it was also irrelevant until I couldn't find any obvious flaws and started considering higher-order explanations. I don't know whether you should re-include tho, I'm still a SO n00b.

Comment: FYI - for code readability, I recommend moving the `i.Stock_out <> d.Stock_out` check from the `INNER JOIN...ON` clause to the `WHERE` clause (not used at present). The columns aren't being used to determine which rows fit together, but rather which results should be output. With an `INNER JOIN` your result set should be the same either way, but it will help clarify the purpose of the different checks.

Comment: @RaheelAdam , Is there a trigger in Table B?

Answer (score 1):

Your `INSERT` is nested under `IF UPDATE(Stock_out)` but then filters on `i.Stock_out <> d.Stock_out` which is redundant.

If `Stock_out` is ever allowed to be `NULL` then your `WHERE` clause will never match (because `NULL IS NULL` evaluates as `true` but `NULL <> NULL` always evaluates as `NULL` [which will not match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777250/2799848)). Please check that.

I am unsure how the [`UPDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql) function responds to multi-row invocations as the Microsoft Docs don't seem to mention it! <sub>Somebody please update me on this.</sub> I would avoid using something with unclear behavior.

Comment: What issue do you see with UPDATE() for multiple rows? if the UPDATE statement affected a set of rows, it would affect the same columns for all of them. 
Even if it updates the column to the original value using some conditional logic, it is still considered an update. 
For example UPDATE T SET Col1 = CASE <something> ELSE Col1 END. There is no way for an UPDATE to affect only some columns for some rows, and other columns for other rows AFAIK.

Comment: `i.Stock_out <> d.Stock_out` is not redundant. The `UPDATE()` function only tells you whether the column has been written to by the triggering statement, and won't detect if the value happens to be same as before. Apparently the OP wants to log *actual* changes, so comparing the `inserted` and `deleted` versions makes perfect sense.

Comment: I figured as such, which is why also checking if the column was specified in the triggering statement is redundant (albeit presumably a small performance optimization). But it is crucial to verify that the value of the column is not being updated to `NULL` or updated from `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, the point about null comparison is totally valid, although it might not be relevant for the OP's use case, because the column could be declared as non-nullable (which, I think you'll agree, would make sense for tables like the OP's)

Comment: I completely agree that the columns should be `NOT NULL`, but I completely disagree that it is reasonable to assume they are declared as such, as my real-world experience screams otherwise :(